# Post запрос PHP, работает через webshtorm а через брауз нет

Tags: php

```php
function start_post(){
    $url = 'https://google.com';
    $params = array(
        'btn'=> 'Готово!'
    );
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => http_build_query($params)
        )
    )));
    $temp_str = '';
    echo $result;
//    echo phpinfo();

}

start_post();
```

При запуске через Phpshtorm (в консоли), всё работает прекрасно, в браузере же пишет вот такое:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\Users\Professional\PhpstormProjects\test\Результат теста.php on line 31

31 строка это вот : `'content' => http_build_query($params)`

В php раскомментировал extension=openssl, программирую на винде.

Comment: Возможно у вас разные ini-файлы для консоли и для fpm (или как вы используете php через браузер). Можно посмотреть используемый файл с помощью [php_ini_loaded_file](https://www.php.net/php_ini_loaded_file).

Answer (score 1):

В конфиге php.ini вам надо добавить строки или убрать комментарии со строк:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension=openssl
```

Comment: Правильно, но этого мало.Я написал что это я сделал ещё в вопросе.

Comment: @antipups а вы сам сервер перезагружали?

Comment: Нет конечно, по какой причине я должен это делать если в самом шторме это работает, я думал и в хроме это будет работать, а как оказалось, нет

Comment: @antipups любые изменения в конфигах должны сопровождаться перезагрузкой

Comment: Но почему тогда в вебшторме все работало?)))))))

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было перезагрузить ide, так как интерпритатор phpshtorma для самого phpstorma а именно консоли, обновляется при запуске СКРИПТА, а для браузера не обновляется, посему нужно его перезапускать (сам phpstorm).